# How to use check box in forms and control the input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-forms

I am having a form and I am getting data from `solutestate` and the output is sent to the first input box using `value={solutestate}` but I want to toggle the output using the checkbox in the input box

Goal: when I check the check box the `solutestate` value should be in the first input box and if unchecked the output of the `solutestate` should be in second input box.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(false);
const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState();
  <input
      className="mr-2 leading-tight"
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={setState}
  />
  <form
      noValidate
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      className="space-x-4"
  >
      <input
         className="shadow"
         {...register("solute")}
         placeholder="SOLUTE"
         onChange={(e) => setSoluteState(e.target.value)}
         value={solutestate}
      />
      <input
         className="shadow"
         {...register("solvent")}
         placeholder="SOLVENT"
      />
  </form>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try below example. initially since checkbox is unchecked value will be in second input.

```
const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState("");
const [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
const [syncToFirst, setSyncToFirst] = useState();
<input
  className="mr-2 leading-tight"
  type="checkbox"
  onChange={(event)=>{syncToFirst(event.target.checked?1:2)}}
/>
<form
  noValidate
  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
  className="space-x-4"
>
  <input
     className="shadow"
     {...register("solute")}
     placeholder="SOLUTE"
     onChange={(e) => syncToFirst === 1 ? setSoluteState(e.target.value) : setInput1(e.target.value)}
     value={syncToFirst === 1 ? solutestate : input1}
  />
  <input
     className="shadow"
     {...register("solvent")}
     placeholder="SOLVENT"
     onChange={(e) => syncToFirst === 2 ? setSoluteState(e.target.value) :input2(e.target.value)}
     value={syncToFirst === 2 ? solutestate : input2}
  />
```

Comment: I am getting false for another input field and when ever I uncheck the values is state value is swapping and the other is false. I have attached the image for your reference in the question

Comment: let me corrected my example

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: false in the input field disappeared but when I check the checkbox the state value is shifting to another input box rather than taking new value their

Comment: I have attached the images you can check what is happening. The value are not retained in the input box rather they are shifting

Comment: I thought you expected it to shift, can you help me understand what is expected?

Comment: I have two input fields. when I press the check box the value stored in `solutestate` and should be in first input box. then if I uncheck the box the value in the first input field should be retained and the new state value should be updated in second input box @Vishwa

Comment: It should not shift. I was expecting to get a new value in second input box when state changes and the first input box before checking the check box should be retained

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239232/discussion-between-harsh-and-vishwa).

Comment: Can you try this updated sample, may be it will work for your scenario?

Comment: It is not working. When I check the checkbox it is copying from the first input field to the second field and later I uncheck its just updating the first field

Comment: can we move to chat?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the code below. This should work
```

```
    const [solutestate, setSoluteState] = useState("");
    const [input2, setInput2] = useState("");
    <input
      className="mr-2 leading-tight"
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={(event)=>{event.target.checked && setInput2(solutestate)}}
    />
    <form
      noValidate
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      className="space-x-4"
    >
      <input
         className="shadow"
         {...register("solute")}
         placeholder="SOLUTE"
         onChange={(e) => setSoluteState(e.target.value)}
         value={solutestate}
      />
      <input
         className="shadow"
         {...register("solvent")}
         placeholder="SOLVENT"
         onChange={(e) => input2(e.target.value)}
         value={input2}
      />
```